# Git: restore files stored in branch A, deleted in B

Tags: git

Given the question title, how would I simply restore the files stored in A?

To be concrete the files exists on a feature branch, which was only created to maintain those files.

I now want to have all those changes in my *devel* branch, but a simple merge of *feature_x* into devel will not contain the deleted files. My guess is that git detects those files have been deleted, so their changes are irrelevant for devel.

I hope a solution does not contain a revert of all rm commits in devel (the outsourcing of the branch was unfortunately not very linear).

EDIT: even a revert looses history, since git only tracks contents, not files. So It does not matter if one uses the revert or the checkout method, they are IMHO equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's ugly but something simple could be the solution:

```
git checkout feature_x -- filename
```

you could also ease this process with:

```
git checkout branchA
for i in "$(git log feature..branchA --summary --diff-filter=D | grep "delete mode" | cut -d " " -f 5-)" ; do
    git checkout feature -- "$i"
done
```

Comment: by using checkout I will loose history. That should not be the case for revert, right?

Comment: that checkout means barely "copy this file from that branch"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd have to restore the deleted files one at a time if you don't want to revert.

This command will give you the commit before the file was deleted.  (it will look back and find the most recent commit where [filename] was changed)

`git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- [filename]`

Then you can check the file out and merge as usual.